# NodaTime OffsetDateTime Binding in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, nodatime

I'm currently using NodaTime OffsetDateTimes in ASP.NET MVC to represent datetimes that I receive from an API.

In the front-end HTML I have a date picker control, which represents dates in the format dd/MM/yyyy.

Once the form containing the date in this format is posted to the server, the OffsetDateTime properties are null.

I've tried modifying the value prior to post, so that it matches the Rfc3339Pattern, but it still reaches the controller as null.

I've created the following custom Model Binder to make this work, and also cater for other instances where dates are passed in the Rfc3339Pattern:

```
public class OffsetDateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        // try Rfc3339Pattern format
        var parseResult = OffsetDateTimePattern.Rfc3339Pattern.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue);

        if (parseResult.Success)
        {
            return parseResult.Value;
        }

        // try dd/MM/yyyy format
        parseResult = OffsetDateTimePattern.Create("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            OffsetDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.MinValue)).Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue);

        if (parseResult.Success)
        {
            return parseResult.Value;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to create a custom ModelBinder for this, or is there something else I can do, similar to the NodaTime JSON.NET seralizer config?

Comment: There's a pull request for a model binder, but I don't know whether that would help you - have a look at https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/pull/368. Have you done any diagnosis in terms of finding whether your model binder has even been called? (I'd recommend constructing the `OffsetDateTimePattern` *once* by the way, using the invariant culture. Also, it's quite odd to use `OffsetDateTime` here when really you're only parsing a date value. I'd use `LocalDate` for this, and construct an `OffsetDateTime` from that later in your code if necessary.)

Comment: Hi Jon, 
Yes the ModelBinder is called once I configure it in the Application_Start - without this I just get nulls for the OffsetDateTimes from the default model binding.

Comment: It also caters for the various date/datetime formats that we can get from our front-end apps.
The reason for parsing a date to OffsetDateTime is that the page model is the same DTO received from the back-end API, which does contain timezone information. 
Probably not the most efficient way, but I'm retrofitting existing apps to be able to handle these timezones.
Thanks for the advice on the OffsetDateTimePattern, I'll try that out.

Comment: So if it's being called, have you stepped through it? Is it returning null, or successfully returning an OffsetDateTime that just isn't being propagated through to your model?

Comment: It's being called and it successfully returns an OffsetDateTime through to my model, so it's a viable solution.
At this stage I guess I'm mostly after clarification as to whether this was the best approach, or if there was an existing package that provided a more comprehensive model binding solution (similar to the NodaTime JSON.NET serialization package).

Comment: Ah, I see... so the code you've got already works. As I mentioned, there's a pull request for something similar to your code, but there's nothing currently packaged up.

Comment: No worries, I'll look into that pull request that you mentioned.
Thanks for your time Jon, it's appreciated.